# How to export access_key and secret_key in codebuild's container as env variables?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-codebuild

When in the AWS Codebuild's build container, I notice that when I run `aws configure list`, I can see a set of `access_key` and `secret_key` on the list.

```
[Container] 2019/08/31 04:27:50 Running command aws configure list 
      Name                    Value             Type    Location 
      ----                    -----             ----    -------- 
   profile                <not set>             None    None 
access_key     ****************BFSR   container-role     
secret_key     ****************DVHJ   container-role     
    region                us-east-1              env    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
```

The keys are different at every build but they allow me to run the aws cli within the build environment through my `buildspec.yml` file. I also presume that it's more secure that I use these temporary one-time access keys in codebuild than to supply another set of fixed access key/secret.

However, I need to export that `access_key` and `secret_key` values as environment variables `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` so that serverless framework can pick them up for deployment.

I've tried to get those values with the command `aws configure get access_key` and `aws configure get secret_key` but both commands give the following error:

```
[Container] 2019/08/31 04:27:12 Command did not exit successfully aws configure get access_key exit status 1
```

For some reason I cannot access those values.

How can I export those the random `access_key` and `secret_key` values within the codebuild's build container as environment variables?

Comment: I believe the correct cli commands are `aws configure get aws_access_key_id` and `aws configure get aws_secret_access_key`. See if that works.

Comment: How did you do it?